# Selecting elements from lists of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
{{0, 0.0621386}, {1, 0.0407129}, {2, 0.0201584}}
```

I wonder how can I select the second element and make two lists as:

```
{{0.0621386}, {0.0407129}, {0.0201584}}
```

and also:

```
 {0.0621386, 0.0407129, 0.0201584}
```

Comment: `lst[[All, 2]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = {{0, 0.0621386}, {1, 0.0407129}, {2, 0.0201584}};

lst[[All, {-1}]]
```

> {{0.0621386}, {0.0407129}, {0.0201584}}

```
lst[[All, -1]]
```

> {0.0621386, 0.0407129, 0.0201584}

You can also use `lst[[;; , {-1}]]` and `lst[[;; ,-1]]`.